# Does this make sense to a native speaker? "despite the real Jones is living in a cave!"

Tags: grammaticality, idioms

The full sentence is this:

> Most of the people just wanna keep up with the Joneses, despite the real Jones is living in a cave!

I heard this out the mouth of a non-native speaker. He wanted to emphasize that, for example, Facebook and Big Tech companies promote the use of social media and digital devices, while themselves having no trust in them. He implied that Mark Zuckerberg himself covers the front camera of his laptop.

Dose this sentence make sense to a native speaker? If I use it, will my audiences get the depth of word?   Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you concerned about? The **Jones** parts makes perfect sense. **Despite** has been used incorrectly.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney I was afraid my audiences don't get what I mean, what word do you suggest instead of **despite** that be correct here?

Comment: **Despite** is a preposition. It must be followed by  noun phrase. Your sentence uses it as if it were a conjunction, and it is followed by a clause. **Although** or **though** would replace **despite**

Comment: Make sense in what sense?  At one level it's an understandable sentence, despite a bit of a grammar error, as pointed out in an answer.  But as a description of the real world, it's nonsense, because (aside from a few hermits and the like) people don't live in caves.  Without much more context (e.g. is it a socio-political rant?) I wouldn't know what the speaker was going on about.

Comment: The way the title is written it makes perfect sense — you've just exposed somebody pretending to be Jones, and are telling us where the real one is! The full question does have some errors though.

Comment: It's a custom extension of an idiom. As with many such extensions, whether it would make sense to any given person is less about English language and more about logic. But using "living in a cave" to suggest having no trust in something is arguably a misuse of that idiom (the idiom would simply imply that they don't use new technology, but Zuckerberg covering his webcam says nothing about how often he uses it nor about him using other cameras). Also, "the real Jones" seems likely to be interpreted as e.g. the real lives of internet personalities, not what Facebook's creator does

Comment: "The real Jones is living in a cave!" is grammatically correct as a sentence by itself, but not after "despite"

Comment: Are you questioning the English-language grammar (i.e. nouns, verbs, etc) or the whether the modified idiom is understandable standalone, or whether the modified idiom accurately and understandably represents the idea professed?

Comment: @CGCampbell "whether the modified idiom is understandable standalone, or whether the modified idiom accurately and understandably represents the idea professed?" This one is my question.

Comment: I suspect the actual sentence was "keep up with the Joneses, despite the real *Joneses* living in a cave! "Joneses" is an irregular plural noun for a group of people all named Jones. There is only a small difference in pronunciation between "Joneses" and "Jones is."

Comment: @user48 note that the concept is not new, for example: [the CEO of Barclays doesn't use credit cards](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2003/oct/17/uk.creditcards) :-)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> Most of the people just wanna keep up with the Joneses, despite the real Jones is living in a cave!

This sentence is understandable to native speakers, but there is a grammar error. You may have misheard the speaker or they may have made a mistake.

**...despite the real *Jones is* living in a cave** is not correct because "despite" needs to be followed by a *noun*, some *thing*, and "is living" is a verb rather than a noun. You could fix it like this:

> ...despite *the fact that* the real Jones is living in a cave!

But I think it more likely that the speaker did not say "Jones is" but rather repeated "Joneses" (meaning "the Jones family")—they just mentioned the Joneses as a group, and it would be strange to suddenly talk about a singular Jones instead. So:

> ...despite the real Joneses living in a cave!

This is grammatically correct because "living" on its own is a *gerund*, not a verb, and a gerund acts as a noun. You could insert "the fact that" and use "are living" to make it match the singular-subject example above, but you don't have to.

As others have said the metaphor is a little forced and doesn't mean exactly "Mark Zuckerberg covers his webcam." For that you might say something like "I guess what's good for the goose **isn't** good for the gander!" (which refers to [another common saying](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/what%27s_good_for_the_goose_is_good_for_the_gander) in English but negates it) or "They want us to do as they say, not as they do" (as EllieK suggests). But in context your meaning will be understood.

Comment: Alternatively—and, to this native speaker’s ear, more idiomatically—using *but* instead of *despite* and keeping the *is*. Absolutely agreed on the repetition of *Joneses*.

Comment: Agree that the metaphor doesn't mean what the OP intends - I read it as a comment about false outward appearances on social media, where people drive themselves crazy trying to keep up with "Joneses" they see their feed, even though the actual life of those Joneses is not nearly as glamorous as their curated profiles suggest.

Comment: "...despite the real Joneses living in a cave!" may be proper grammar, but it sounds non idiomatic to me as a native speaker. I would say the entire sentence as "Most of the people just wanna keep up with the Joneses, **even if** the **[]** Jones**es** **are** living in a cave!

Comment: Thanks for your great alternatives, but if I wanna use the sentence I said, in your opinion, it's not better to use a "themselves" at the end of the sentence? I mean the sentence becomes like this: **despite the fact that real Joneses are living in a cave themselves!**?

Comment: @user48 no, that adds nothing at all to the meaning and makes the sentence sound more awkward. Also you left out a "the" in front of "real Joneses."

Comment: For completeness, note that many traditional grammars would have "despite the real Joneses’ living in a cave" with a possessive "Joneses’". See [the Wikipedia article on gerunds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund#%22Gerund%22_clauses_with_a_specified_subject), which says: "Nonetheless, the possessive construction with -ing clauses is very rare in present-day English."

Comment: Another possibility: “Even though the real Jones is living in a cave.”

Answer (score 15):

*Keeping up with the Joneses*, is a common expression.  It means that you want to look like you are doing as well financially as your neighbor, neighbor being defined in the broadest terms.  Not strictly limited to financial success, it also includes things like quality of life (i.e. am I happy), success of your children, and other indicators of success.

Your example sentence states that the Joneses, being the people we are trying to keep up with, are not doing any better that we are.  They are possibly doing worse than we are.  This sentence also subtly implies that the Joneses we are tying to keep up with are not our neighbors but must be someone else.  Maybe these Joneses are media creations?

I don't think the non-native speaker you mention is using the phrase correctly.  The statement, when it includes the part about Joneses living in caves, is ironic and it would be used that way.  The irony of Zuckerberg covering his laptop camera, however, is not captured in the *Keeping up with the Joneses* phrase. The laptop camera irony is a *Do as I say, not as I do* type of irony whereas the *Joneses* irony is different.

Comment: Why in your opinion I can't use this sentence as an irony? I mean should we always use an idiom in just **one** specific situation? (here neighbor)

Comment: @user48 - The statement, when it includes the part about Joneses living in caves,  is ironic and it would be used that way.  The irony of Zuckerberg covering his laptop camera, however, is not captured in the *Keeping up with the Joneses* phrase.  That phrase illustrates a different kind of irony.  The laptop camera irony is a *Do as a say, not as I do* type of irony.  Whereas the Joneses irony is different and not as easily explained.

Comment: This last comment you've written, "The laptop camera irony is..." deserves to be in the answer.  It's an important clarification.

Comment: I think the irony kind of works — the point about the cave isn't that they're so destitute that they have to live in a cave, but rather that the Zuckerbergs of the world are so afraid of the technology they themselves created (and made all the would-be startup founders want to chase) that they are _hiding_ in a (primitive) cave.

Comment: @user48 The ‘Joneses’ idiom refers to comparing yourself to your peers: people who may be ever-so-slightly better-off than you but still within the same (usually) middle-class ‘league’. It refers to the struggle not to fall behind the average person. Zuckerberg et al. can hardly be called your peers: they are not ‘average’ people, they are elites who tower above the Joneses of the world.

Comment: I think the person who said "keeping up with the Joneses" may misunderstand that idiom, perhaps due to the TV show "Keeping Up With the Kardashians", which is about an ultra-rich family (and in this case, "keeping up with" doesn't mean achieving equal status, but learning about their activities). But I agree with @ChrisBouchard about the cave analogy.

Comment: Yes, there is some irony in it. ‘Keeping up with the Joneses’ is just the wrong idiom to evoke it.

Answer (score 4):

I think the origin of the saying is British petty snobbery. The Joneses (plural) are a family of hypothetical or generic better-off neighbours. I would want to see "Most of the people just **want to** keep up with the Joneses, **despite the fact that** the real **Joneses are** living in a cave!"

Comment: One explanation for the expression "Keeping up with the Joneses" refers to a mid 19th-century Hudson Valley (New York) socialite Elizabeth Schermerhorn Jones, whose ostentatious lifestyle and palatial estate aroused the envy of her (also wealthy) neighbors, who strove to keep up with her spending. Regarding the "real Joneses" living in a cave, that would imply a rejection of modern life, the opposite of frantic spending to appear to be in the same league as someone else -- the chase for social status.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm parsing it in an antiquated way, but the whole sentence is resolving as

> Most of the people just wanna keep up with the Joneses, despite [implied: the fact that] the real Jones (i.e.: 'Mx. Jones', the head of the Jones family) is living in a cave [intending to illustrate the disparity between apparent and substantive material conditions]!

I don't feel there is any critical barrier to understanding, and it could even be somewhat poetic.

Answer (score 0):

The expression “Keeping up with the Joneses” [was popularized in a newspaper comic strip from 1913,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keeping_Up_with_the_Joneses_(comics)#:%7E:text=Keeping%20Up%20with%20the%20Joneses%20%20%20,April%2016%2C%201938%20%203%20more%20rows%20) and today is a disapproving way to say that someone is trying to match someone else in conspicuous consumption.

It would be appropriate if, say, all the billionaires were all competing to build their own spaceships, even bigger and flashier than Elon Musk’s, and then Elon Musk announced he was selling SpaceX and donating the money to public health in Africa.  Or if Mark Zuckerberg had the most incredible backgrounds on his Zoom meetings, or the fanciest costumes, and everyone were trying to outdo him, and then he just started turning his camera off so they could focus on getting work done.

That’s not what’s happened here, though: the irony is that Zuckerberg wants privacy for no one but himself.  I like the suggestion of, “Do as Zuck says, not as he does.”  Or maybe, “Zuck’s built a glass house, for us, and now he’s throwing stones.”  Or just something sarcastic about how much Zuck values privacy.

There’s also, as others have mentioned, a grammatical error in the sentence.  If we were talking about the scenario where the billionaire who started the competition has bowed out of it, I might say something like, “and Mr. Jones has just gone off to live in a cave,” or “but Mr. Jones has moved into a cave with a goatskin and some sticks.” Either of those gets across that Jones used to show off, but has stopped.

Answer (score -1):

It should be "Despite the fact the real
Jones is living in a cave, most people
just wanna keep up with the Joneses."